# Two AJAX calls: upon success render the content to the browser at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got problem with two AJAX calls. I'm calling it from a jquery object. I want upon success for the AJAX call who get the content first to wait to render it until the second AJAX request also recieves the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(function() {
   var executedAmount = 0;
   var datas = {};
   //Ajax call 1:
   $.ajax({
      'success': function(data) {
          executedAmount++;
          datas[0] = data;
          callBack();
      }
   });
   //Ajax call 2:
   $.ajax({
      'success': function(data2) {
          executedAmount++;
          datas[1] = data2;
          callBack();
      }
   });
   function callBack() {
      if (executedAmount == 2) {
          //Do something with datas here
      }
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can use jQuery 1.5, then this would answer your problem.

Introducing [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

> **Example:** Execute a function after ***two
>   ajax requests are successful***. (See the
>   jQuery.ajax() documentation for a
>   complete description of success and
>   error cases for an ajax request).

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
        page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively */
   var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   if ( /Whip It/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
      alert("First page has 'Whip It' somewhere.");
   }
});
```

Comment: This looks like the most efficient answed yet. I will test it

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above answer, you could just measure the length of `datas` instead of having a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

what if you use this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('selector').jaxStop(function() {
      //Do some thing
         WhenAjaxEnds();
    });
});

function  WhenAjaxEnds(){
  //do something here ....
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: when you have this code in your script, jquery checks whether there are any Ajax requests. If none remain, jquery triggers the ajaxStop event then  WhenAjaxEnds() will execute. let me know what you are trying to do after ajax end, then i can be more specific.

Comment: this solution is just like "last resort" - what if there are other ajax calls, and you just really want to know two specific ajax call. ;)

Comment: @Reigel , agreed on that case.